# What possible values are JsonOptions in GlueContext#getSinkWithFormat

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Look at [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/JoinAndRelationalize.scala):

```
glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(connectionType = "s3", 
   options = JsonOptions(
      Map("path" -> outputLgSingleDir,
          "partitionKeys" -> List("org_name"))),
  format = "parquet", transformationContext = "")
.writeDynamicFrame(lHistory)
```

What possible values for `JsonOptions` are?

Comment: Here's the documentation for all the options available. I post in comments as moderators do not consider this an answer. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html